# Class with repeated buttons android

Tags: java, android, class, button

I have several classes with the same buttons. How can I combine them into one class rather than writing them in each class? 
Thanks

Comment: Put the buttons in a separate class, then include this class in the other classes and re-use those resources.

Comment: What does "same" buttons mean? Do they look the same? Do they perform exactly the same action?

Comment: Yes, perform the same actions.
<code>
Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Class.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
</code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a bean class for buttons and use them using getter and setters throughout your app.
create buttons dynamically

```
http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/
```

this link will help you to implement such things..
That may solve ur problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the functionality of your button are different? So you can inherit some classes from base main class and put your functionality in them. Or use one class and use a flag to decide what functionality you should use.